# Something wrong with printf or something

Tags: c, printf

I am reading some material about safe programming,When I enter :
./a.out  %.622496x%.622496x%n

./a.out  %..622496x%n

./a.out  %.633x%.63336x%n

./a.out  %.6edd33x%.63336x%n

Some will got coredump some will not,can't figure out why they print all the 0.

Here is the code example.c
gcc example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[512]="";
    strncpy(buffer,argv[1],500);
    printf(buffer);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What you're doing, getting format specifiers as input from a user, is *bad* and a great way to have security problems in your program. All the format specifiers you provide expects arguments, the `"%n"` will even cause `printf` to *write* somewhere in memory. All leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Perhaps you need to read more about [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to sanitize your inputs before displaying such a string.

As you have `%xxx` is the string, `printf` interpret these as potential arguments, and then will try to get them, hence the core dump. But this gets further, as this can mean security attacks through this mechanism. In a way, this is the C equivalent of SQL injections.

As @TypeIA, the proper way to do so is to consider `buffer` as an argument to the formatting string (`printf("%s", buffer)`), not the formatting string itself. This is also a reason why some compilers would warn if you create a function with arguments `( char * format, ... );` (not const).

Comment: thanks,I always use print(buffer) ,It is not a safe way,when dealing with user input,thanks for your answer.